# Py4JJavaError: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C

Tags: java, python, pyspark

I am trying to read a txt file through spark and below are the commands i used.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
Inp = sc.textFile("C://Users//XXXX//Downloads//number_list.txt")
list1 = lines.collect()
```

I get the below error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
```

I have Java 8 and spark 2.4.5

I am new to PySpark and would really appreciate some good pointers to learn more about PySpark.

Comment: try with replacing // with \\

Comment: What platform are you running this code on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on macOS?

I got same error

> No FileSystem for scheme: C

when I running a script I found online.

For my issue, it is because the original script is written on Windows, while I am running it on macOS.

After changing the line from

```
sc.checkpoint("C:/checkpoint/")
```

to something like

```
sc.checkpoint("/Users/me/Downloads/checkpoint/")
```

The error was gone.